# Unity3D Input.getAxis() slowly dies instead of returning 0

Tags: c#, input, unity-game-engine

I'm using `Input.GetAxis()` in Unity3D with keyboard (WASD), I printed out it's values in the `FixedUpade()` function, and when I release a button it returns values like: 1.0f, 0.7f, 0.4f, 0.0f, instead of instant 0.0f.

Is there a way to achieve instant 0.0f on releasing the button? (changing the value to 0 when it's smaller than 1 is not an option)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetAxis()` will have smoothing applied to its values. If you want to use unfiltered data (0 or +/-1 for keyboards) use [`GetAxisRaw()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxisRaw.html) instead.

Comment: Keep in mind that in majority of cases, this smoothing may actually be a good thing. If the you want to treat direction and WASD buttons as a buttons instead of axis, you're better use the button functions instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the range of values that `GetAxis()` provides (smooth, graduated movement) but want the input value to return to zero *immediately* when the player releases the button/key (e.g. to halt animations), you can use `GetAxisRaw()` in your logic like so:

```cs
float inputX = 0;
    
// reset X after player has stopped pressing
if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") != 0)
    inputX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
```